# what join is caused by "and"?

Tags: sql, localdb

I have a localDB database that includes the following tables:

UserProfile, which contains:

```
UserId  UserName
1           Adam
```

webpages_Roles, which contains:

```
RoleID RoleName
1      user
2      admin
```

webpages_UsersInRoles, which has two columns (UserId, RoleId), and is blank.

I want a query to add a user by name into a role by name. 
to figure out what to insert, if I run:

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID 
FROM UserProfile, webpages_Roles 
WHERE UserProfile.UserName = 'Adam' 
   OR webpages_roles.RoleName = 'admin';
```

I get this:

```
UserId  RoleId
1       2
1       1
```

which makes sense; it's a cross join.  But I basically just want to run two separate selects at once and stick them together.  I tried this:

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID 
FROM UserProfile, webpages_Roles 
WHERE UserProfile.UserName = 'Adam' 
  AND webpages_roles.RoleName = 'admin';
```

and it worked; I got UserId 1 and RoleId 2. but I don't understand that "and"; isn't it like comparing apples to oranges? shouldn't it be a syntax error? Is localDB actually running two selects and joining the results, perhaps by line number?

Comment: The possible duplicate question is related but is far from being an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this query:

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID 
FROM UserProfile, webpages_Roles
WHERE UserProfile.UserName = 'Adam' AND webpages_roles.RoleName = 'admin';
```

You are doing a `cross join`.  You should get in the habit of being specific about the cross join, and use `cross join` rather than `,`.  In any case, this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID
FROM (select u.*
      from UserProfile u
      where u.UserName = 'Adam'
     ) cross join
     (select w.*
      from webpages_Roles w
      WHERE w.RoleName = 'admin'
     ) w
```

When doing a `cross join` you are creating a cartesian product -- each row from the first table is matched to all the rows in the other table.  The `where` clause then is a filter on this result set.

If you want to align data, that is harder.  Here is one method using SQL Server syntax:

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID
FROM (select u.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from UserProfile u
      where u.UserName = 'Adam'
     ) u join
     (select w.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from webpages_Roles w
      WHERE w.RoleName = 'admin'
     ) w
     on u.seqnum = w.seqnum
```

Comment: "The where clause then is a filter on this result set."

That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you select from multiple tables, you are actually implicitly joining the tables.

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID 
FROM UserProfile, webpages_Roles;
```

The above query would return something like:

```
UserId  UserName  RoleID RoleName
1           Adam  1      user
1           Adam  2      admin
```

So when you add the where clause:

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID 
FROM UserProfile, webpages_Roles 
WHERE UserProfile.UserName = 'Adam' AND webpages_roles.RoleName = 'admin';
```

It only returns the rows where the UserProfile.Username is 'Adam' and webpages_roles.RoleName is 'admin'.

Answer (score 1):

the reason that this is correct and not an error of any kind is the following.
When yo do

```
SELECT UserId, RoleID
FROM UserProfile, webpages_Roles
```

without a `WHERE` clause, what you get in standard SQL is the cartesian product of the relations, ie, `UserProfile x webpages_Roles`

which is in turn a realtion, in your case (as shown in DiscoInfiltrator's answer),

```
UserId  UserName  RoleID RoleName
1           Adam  1      user
1           Adam  2      admin
```

That means that this part of the query `WHERE UserProfile.UserName = 'Adam' 
  AND webpages_roles.RoleName = 'admin';` acts on a relation containing both the UserName and the RoleName attributes,

Hope this clarifies, cheers